rememberAnimatedVectorPainter speed up the animation dinamically
I have an animated-vector that I want to change the speed dynamically in jetpack compose, here is what I have at the moment.your text
I'm using the LaunchedEffect in order to loop the animation, and currently it works for looping, but now I want a way to change the animation speed.I tried to change the delay value, with different approach but it cut off the animation in whenever I change the speed to for example (animation.totalDuration * 0.8).toLong()
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
@Composable
fun Greeting(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val animation = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(id = R.drawable.my_animation2)

    val painterFirst = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(
        animatedImageVector = animation,
        atEnd = atEnd
    )

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            atEnd = !atEnd
            delay(animation.totalDuration.toLong())
        }
    }

    Column {
        Image(painter = painterFirst, contentDescription = "null")
    }
}

